# how to traverse an array in a recursion using pointers

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, recursion

i have a function e.g `int trav(int **arr, int col, int row);` how do i use this to traverse an array using the function recursively without the use of vectors or bitwise operators or static variables or loops inside the recursive function? My instructor taught this in class but i couldn't get a clear understanding of what he was trying to do. So i have come here to seek help before a test comes up on this and i fail miserably. I read a lot about similar stuff on this website however people have mostly either used vectors or bitwise operators which we haven't been taught yet so I don't understand what they mean. Please if you could explain this to me I am curious

**this is for c++**

Comment: What does bitwise operators have to do with traversing an array?  Also, this; `int trav(int **arr, int col, int row);` gives no information on what you're really suppose to accomplish.  In short, we have little to no information on what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming an iterative function

```
void trav(int **arr, int col, int row)
{
    for (int i = 0; i != col; ++i) {
        for (int j = 0; j != col; ++j) {
            f(arr[i][j]);
        }
    }
}
```

Using a single do-while approach, it would be:

```
void trav(int **arr, int col, int row)
{
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;
    do {
        f(arr[i][j]);
        if (++j == row) {
            j = 0;
            ++i;
        }
    } while (i != col);
}
```

recursive function might look like:

```
void trav_rec(int **arr, int col, int row, int i = 0, int j = 0)
{
    f(arr[i][j]);
    if (++j == row) {
        j = 0;
        if (++i == col) {
            return;
        }
    }
    trav_rec(arr, col, row, i, j);
}
```